# How to find last position of substring in SAS (oposite of index function)

Tags: function, indexing, sas

There is a string '6017>6025>6023>6022>6025>6032'. How can we know the last position of '6025'? index function only returns first occurrence of string. It's hard to use reverse function because it's not finding one character. Is there any good idea?

Comment: Why not reverse the string and use index to search for `5206`?

Comment: @kaybee99 because that's the same as counting from right to left. It will still return the first match, which in the example is 6, not 21 that the OP wants.  You'd have to subtract that from the length, in which case it's easier to use `find` as per the answer from @sushil

Answer (score 12):

You can use FIND function to solve the problem. Check out the find function on the [SAS documentation](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/lrdict/64316/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a002267763.htm). For your problem the following syntax of  find function can help.

```
FIND(input string,search string,start position)
```

So to look for text in reverse direction, you can use negative value of START POSITION which would be greater than the length of the string. So, if the length is 8 then start position would be -8 or -9 or -10 etc. to search in reverse direction

Check out the following sample code.

```
data _null_;
    x='6017>6025>6023>6022>6025>6032';
    y=find(x,'6025',-length(x));
putlog _all_;
run;
```

Comment: Thanks @sushil, that's what I want.

Comment: You should mark the question answered if you are happy with the answer

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to use FINDW() instead of INDEX() or FIND() to avoid matching only part of a value from a word in the string.  The FINDW() function allows you to use modifiers to have it do things like search from the end to the front and strip leading/trailing spaces.

```
data test;
  length string $100 word $30 ;
  string = '6017>6025>6023>6022>6025>6032';
  do word='6025','6032','6017','602';
    location = findw(string,word,'>','bt');
    put word= location=;
  end;
run;
```

Results:

```
word=6025 location=21
word=6032 location=26
word=6017 location=1
word=602 location=0
```

Answer (score 0):

and you can used FIND function like write bellow, where 20 it is start position for searching

```
    data _null_;
        x='6017>6025>6023>6022>6025>6032';
        y=find(x,'6025',20);
    putlog _all_;
    run;
```